# Display Google Map based on ASP.NET/SQL database fields Address, City, Country, Postcode?

Tags: asp.net, dictionary

We have a backend SQL database on our ASP.NET website that holds each customer's:

Business Name,
Street Address,
City/Town,
Country,
Postcode/ZIP

We want to create a contact.aspx?customerid=123456 webpage which displays these details (depending on customer profile chosen) and then a medium sized map for their address underneath the contact details.

We can get ASP.NET to write some HTML code for the page depending on the customer.

What exactly should we get ASP.NET to write for the HTML? Do we need to ask the customer to get the latitude and longitude co-ordinates first and load them into their database profile? Or can we just pass the address fields above to the page?

TIA
Mark

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [google maps geocoding service](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/) to convert your addresses to lat/lng points which can be transferred to the map as a parameter.